# Watch a collectionGroup with Firestore using Cloud Functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm working on a Firestore DB that uses collectionGroups.

The collectionGroup in question is a collection of 'Fights'.

When a new fight is created I would like to use the onCreate method in a cloud function to watch for new 'Fight' entries and then add some meta data to them. Ideally It would look something like the pseudo code below

```
export const placeFightersInEvent = functions.firestore
  .collectionGroup('fights/{fightId}')
  .onCreate(async (fightSnapshot, context) => {
    // get metadata and add to the newly created 'fight'
  });
```

I'm using the most up to date versions of the firebase functions and admin sdk but I can't seem to find an available function to do this. Is it possible to watch collection groups in this way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Currently this is not possible for fights subcollections at any depth.  Please [file a feature request with Firebase support](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support) if you need to do this.

However, if you are only ever working with a fights subcollections at a known depth, then this might work just as well anyway:

```
export const placeFightersInEvent = functions.firestore
  .document('{coll}/{doc1}/fights/{doc2}')
  .onCreate(async (fightSnapshot, context) => {
    // get metadata and add to the newly created 'fight'
  });
```

It should only trigger for new fights nested below documents in any top-level collection, so it is not a true collection group event handler.  But you could just create new functions for each depth required.

Comment: Thanks Doug, I think this will work fine for me. So ```.document('events/{eventID}/fights/{fightId}')``` Will watch all the fights created in the events fight subcollections and pass me both and eventId and fightId when created correct?

Comment: That's what I'd expect, yes.

Comment: Just to clarify for anyone in the future, access eventID using context.params.eventID and fightId using context.params.fightId. This works perfect. Thanks again.