# Read data every second cloud function firestore and update data one by one for multiple data

Tags: express, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, cloud, task-queue

What best choice for read data every second in firestore cloud function and update it continuously if there is data exist with queue.
I am use pubsub in minute for trigger run data in background then use cron.schedule for read data every seconds and update if data exist.
Any solution better for this?

For now my code like below for read data every second

```js
 const autoUpdate = functions
      .pubsub.schedule('* * * * *')
      .onRun(async (context) => {
        // read every second
        cron.schedule('* * * * * *', async () => {
          let itemQueue = [];
          let isProcess = false;

          const getData = await db
            .collectionGroup('products')
            .where('endDate', '==', null)
            .get();
          
          getData.docs.forEach(doc => {
          const data = doc.data();
          itemQueue.push(data);

          itemQueue = itemQueue.filter((val) => val.stat[itemQueue.stat.length - 1].currentStat == 'primary');

          const processQueue = async () => {
            if (itemQueue.length === 0) {
              // No queue left
              isProcessing = false;
              return;
            }
  
            // Take first queue from array
            const item = itemQueue.shift();
  
            if (item.length == 0) {
              functions.logger.log('no data');
            } else {
              item.forEach(async (doc) => {
                const data = doc.data();
  
                const getData = await db
                  .collectionGroup('products')
                  .where('uid', '==', data.uid)
                  .get();
  
                // update products
                getData.forEach(async (doc) => {
                  await doc.ref
                    .update({
                      endDate: nowDate,
                      stat: admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(newStat),
                    })
                    .then(async () => {
                      functions.logger.log('Update');
                    })
                    .catch((error: any) => {
                      functions.logger.log(error);
                    });
                });
              })
            }
            
            setTimeout(() => {
                // Continue next queue
                processQueue();
              }, 1000);
          }

          if (!isProcess) {
            isProcess = true;
            processQueue();
          }
        });
      }
    );
```

That code run and will update if endDate null and currenStat is primary.
But the result sometime field stat become duplicate with different datetime like this. Maybe the queue not running well.

```
{
  stat: new status,
  endDate: new date
},
{
  stat: new status,
  endDate: new date
}
```

I want field stat update only once.

Answer (score 1):

> I am use pubsub in minute for trigger run data in background then use cron.schedule for read `data every seconds and update if data exist. Any solution better for this?

Yes there is, with firestore triggers on the specified collectionGroup depth means `products` subcollection should only exist on the specified depth level only then you can listen to the updates in that collectionGroup documents as follows :

```js
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";

admin.initializeApp();

export const updateUser = functions.firestore
    // Assuming your products live at this depth
    .document("users/{userId}/products/{productId}")    
    .onUpdate((change) => {
        // updated data
        const newValue = change.after.data();

        // Last Data
        const previousValue = change.before.data();

        // Add some conditional logic to exit infinite loop ex
        if (newValue.count === previousValue.count) return null;

        // Retrieve the current count of name changes
        let count = newValue.name_change_count;
        if (!count) {
            count = 0;
        }

        // update data
        return change.after.ref.update({
            endDate: admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
            name_change_count: count + 1,
            stat: admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion("New Value")
        })
    });
```

With this you can even listen up to every second but then you cannot query on the trigger that part you have to do inside the trigger function by sanitizing the data with if statements. You only need to take care about infinite loops occurring when updating the same document  which you can get more info [prevent infinite loops](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events?gen=1st#:%7E:text=Note%3A%20Any%20time%20you%20write%20to%20the%20same%20document%20that%20triggered%20a%20function%2C%20you%20are%20at%20risk%20of%20creating%20an%20infinite%20loop.%20Use%20caution%20and%20ensure%20that%20you%20safely%20exit%20the%20function%20when%20no%20change%20is%20needed.)

Reference :

- **[Cloud Firestore triggers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events?gen=1st)**
- [Watch a collectionGroup with Firestore using Cloud Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58186741/watch-a-collectiongroup-with-firestore-using-cloud-functions)

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer. But if use onUpdate there must be trigger first for change database product right? 
So first i use function every second for change database product then use functionn onUpdate for change data ?

Comment: No function should be run by us manually we can just create document using firebase admin sdk or client sdk then to listen for creation events use `onCreate` trigger and do the stuff related to newer document I recommend you to go through [firestore triggers docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events?gen=1st).

Comment: but i want use every second for update data. Because in product i use function with countdown do in client side. And i need every second for run in background

Comment: @AlkimAl Firestore trigger gets executed the moment that document changes I think you are missing the point about triggers